# Using Python's xml.dom.minidom

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to use Python's xml.dom.minidom, and I'm getting the following error:

```
>>> from xml.dom import minidom
>>> xdocument = minidom.Document()
>>> xrss = minidom.Element("rss")
>>> xdocument.appendChild(xrss)
<DOM Element: rss at 0xc1d0f8>
>>> xchannel = minidom.Element("channel")
>>> xrss.appendChild(xchannel)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 3.2\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in ?
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "c:\Python24\Lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 123, in appendChild
    _clear_id_cache(self)
  File "c:\Python24\Lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1468, in _clear_id_cache
    node.ownerDocument._id_cache.clear()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_id_cache'
>>>
```

Anyone has any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xdocument.createElement('name')` to create new elements. This is the standard way to do that in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `xdocument.appendChild(xrss)` with `xrss = xdocument.appendChild(xrss)`. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Node.appendChild):

> Node.appendChild(newChild) Add a new
>   child node to this node at the end of
>   the list of children, returning
>   newChild. If the node was already in
>   in the tree, it is removed first.

So you need to assign `xrss` to the returned element from `appendChild`.